# mix html template with php code : php html template

Tags: php, mysql

I create a dynamic website using php/mysql. my template for print data using pure php code + html . now , *better, optimized, faster way* for *Structure* of mix php + html ? ( without template engine )

for ***each*** page i have : ex.1 ( php code before wrapper )

```
<?PHP include ( DEFINE_SITE . '/templates/header.php' );

// isset : post : get : SELECT : INSERT ... Or ANY CODE OF PHP
 ?>

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="leftsidebar"><?PHP // Left DATA ?></div>
<div id="centercontent">

<?PHP // while {} Print result of php  ANY LOOPS ..... ?>

</div>
<div id="rightsidebar"><?PHP // Right DATA ?></div>
</div>
<?PHP include ( DEFINE_SITE . '/templates/footer.php' ); ?>
```

for ***each*** page i have : ex.2  ( after side bar and before center content )

```
<?PHP include ( DEFINE_SITE . '/templates/header.php' );

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="leftsidebar"><?PHP // Left DATA ?></div>
<?PHP // isset : post : get : SELECT : INSERT ... Or ANY CODE OF PHP ?>
<div id="centercontent">

<?PHP // while {} Print result of php  ANY LOOPS ..... ?>

</div>
<div id="rightsidebar"><?PHP // Right DATA ?></div>
</div>

<?PHP include ( DEFINE_SITE . '/templates/footer.php' );?>
```

Which is better? e.x 1 or e.x 2 ? your opinion ?

Comment: optimized structure, faster loading.

Comment: Define optimized structure. Also, faster loading? They're the same basically. If anything, you won't shave off a millisecond between the two. If you want performance, don't use `include`, that forces the OS to do the `stat` on the file. However, you should never trade (minimal) performance for the sake of code clarity and maintainability.

Comment: @N.B. Couldn't agree more. Just upgrade your hardware, rather than write unmaintainable code. As for OP examples, I cannot see any difference between them - performance wise, it doesn't really matter whether you execute your code before or after outputting some static content.

Answer (score 0):

why the aversion to a template engine?  In reality, PHP is a template engine, but perhaps if you checked a few out (like Twig) it might help you in designing something more flexible, fast and responsive without the template engine....  or you might start to love it, like me ;-)

Comment: yeap! Twig is best of template engine After RainTPL, Smarty  with cache support .But I'm currently using it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you keep your HTML and PHP separated. If you don't want to use a template system why don't you do it like this?

Make a HTML template:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="leftsidebar">{LEFT}</div>
    <div id="centercontent">{CONTENT}</div>
    <div id="rightsidebar">{RIGHT}</div>
</div>
```

In a different php file:

```
$content = file_get_contents('template.html');
$templateVars = array();

startVar('CONTENT');
echo '<p>This is the content.</p>'; // New template vars are also allowed
endVar('CONTENT');

echo replaceTemplateVars($content);

/**
 * Replace template variables recursively with the key-value pairs that are in the $templateVars queue
 * @param string $content (default NULL) is code to convert.
 * @return the string that is replaced
 */
function replaceTemplateVars($content = NULL)
{
    global $templateVars;
    $matches = array();
    preg_match_all("/{[A-Z0-9_:]*}/", $content, $matches); // $matches = All vars found in your template
    foreach($matches[0] as $key)
    {
        if(isset($templateVars[substr($key, 1, -1)]))
        {
            $content = str_replace($key, $templateVars[substr($key, 1, -1)], $content); // Substitute template var with contents
        }
        else
        {
            $content = str_replace($key, "", $content); // Remove empty template var from template
        }
    }

    // Check if the replacement has entered any new template variables, if so go recursive and replace these too
    if(preg_match_all("/{[A-Z0-9_:]*}/", $content, $matches))
    {
        $content = replaceTemplateVars($content);
    }

    return $content;
}

/**
 * Start output buffer for a template key
 * @param string $key is not used. Only for overview purposes
 */
function startVar($key)
{
    ob_start();
}

/**
 * End output buffer for a template key and store the contents of the output buffer in the template key
 * @param string $key
 */
function endVar($key)
{
    setVar($key, ob_get_contents());
    ob_end_clean();
}

/**
 * @param string $key to store value in
 * @param mixed $value to be stored
 */
function setVar($key, $value)
{
    global $templateVars;
    $templateVars[$key] = $value;
}
```

And this is what you get on your screen:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="leftsidebar"></div>
    <div id="centercontent"><p>This is the content.</p></div>
    <div id="rightsidebar"></div>
</div>
```

So preprocessing is done first and at the end all html code is outputted.

Of course you could add functions like `startPrependVar()` and `startAppendVar()` and wrap everything into a Template class to get rid of the global scope.